# Prove $λ$ must divide one of $x$, $y$, or $z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $λ = (3 + \sqrt{−3})/2 \in \Bbb Q[\sqrt{−3}]$. Prove that if $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$, and $x$, $y$, $z$ are quadratic integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{−3}]$, then $λ$ must divide one of $x$, $y$, or $z$.

**What I thought:**

if $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$, then $\beta^3 = \pm 1 \mod \alpha^3$, then we can show that if alpha doesn't divide $x,y,z$ say that: $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (\pm 1) + (\pm 1) + (\pm 1) \mod \alpha^3$ which is impossible if $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$

Comment: What I thoight: if gcd(alpha,beta)=1, then beta^3 = +/- 1 (mod alpha^3)

Then we can show that if alpha doesn't divide x,y,z say that:

x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (+/- 1) + (+/- 1) + (+/- 1) (mod alpha^3)

which is impossible if

x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: You should add this to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @solidsnake Done

Comment: @Rachel You have to say if just one or maybe two (I don't know) because (x,y,z)= $\lambda$(x,y,z) projectively so for the three is trivial.

Comment: @Rachel Have you read somewhere your question or it is of your own. Not only the cubic of Fermat but all curve V: $x^3$ + $y^3$ = A$z^3$ with A cube free has an infinity of quadratic points, even when the rank is zero, and it is not hard to find examples. But not in any predetermined of these fields because of the hard diophantine equation implicate. Besides all V admits complex multiplication by √(-3) but it seems despite this that there are not much of the integers you ask. (sorry for bad english)

Comment: @luisgomezsanchez So am I correct or no?

Comment: I recently just read your thought. For coprime in your ring the gcd must be a unit, not necessarily 1. The units in this case are the six roots of $x^6$ = 1.

Comment: @luizgomezsanchez If you can, can you provide a solution?

Comment: It is maybe useful for you: your ($\lambda$ - 1) is a 6-root of 1 so a unit of your ring.

Comment: I try but I have the problem I told you. Just I have seen what your lambda minus 1 is. However the hard is to stablish what ring is the object of the problem (it is maybe trivial).

Comment: @luizgomezsanchez Can you show your thoughts. I want to see exactly what you are saying.

Comment: Unless the complex multiplication by square root of -3 the other thing of my second comment is of my own (and not wrong!). The group of units is deduced of general solutions for imaginary quadratic fields in the (extraordinary) book of Pierre Samuel Théorie Algébrique des nombres (it is sure there is a traduction to English). What I can say you now is  lambda minus 1 is probably a generator of the group of units (see my third comment)